# What is oldest known coal source?

Tags: paleontology, mining, coal, energy

I read coal form in all geologic times but what is oldest know coal source?

Answer (score 3):

The first coal deposits were laid during the [Carboniferous period](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carboniferous), between 358.9 million years ago and 298.9 million years ago.

Within this period, the early [Mississippian](http://www.gondwanaresearch.com/hp/paleo2.pdf) period from 358.9 to 346.7 Mya, was when the first coal deposits were being laid. During this period, coal was being laid in what is now eastern North America, specifically the [Kentucky](http://www.uky.edu/KGS/fossils/fossil-region-Mississippian-period.php) region.

Comment: There are pre-Carbonfierous coals from the Devonian - some of economic importance - e.g. in Russia https://pubs.acs.org/doi/pdf/10.1021/ef00048a039